# Инициализировать char массив из главного метода

Tags: java

Пишу программу с классом, в котором нужно символьный массив преобразовать в текстовый. При инициализации символьного массива возникает ошибка.

```
public class overloadOfMethod {
public void ovrld(char[] array){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        overloadOfMethod obj = new overloadOfMethod();
        obj.ovrld({'*', '+'});
    }
```

Comment: "возникает ошибка" - секретная?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
obj.ovrld(new char[] {'*', '+'});
          ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! помогло!

Comment: @ANDR Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа/комментариев.